# finding number of people in a table that are NOT in other tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have 3 tables (let's say A, B, and C), and I have a common key column in all 3, called G.
I need a script to find the number of G that are in A (the main table - Level 1) that are not in either of B or C (level 2 tables). Basically, I want to left join a table on the result of full join of other 2 tables.

I tried the left join but the result is not correct. I used following script:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.G)
FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON A.G = B.G
     FULL JOIN C ON A.G = C.G
WHERE (B.G IS NULL) OR (C.G IS NULL)
```

Appreciate your help.

**P.S.**
Choice of correct answer is based on the superiority in processing time. I ran both alternatives (exists vs. left joins) on my data set (which is relatively large and time consuming).

`LEFT JOIN` approach (selected answer) is far more process efficient than the `EXISTS`. It took former approach 0:23 minutes, compared to 7:52 minutes for later approach.

Comment: Why are you doing a full join to C instead of a left join.

Comment: Yes, I did the full join wrongly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are close - You need a left join to both `B` and `C` tables as well as `AND` instead of `OR` in your `where` clause:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT A.G)
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B ON A.G = B.G
LEFT JOIN C ON A.G = C.G
WHERE B.G IS NULL
AND C.G IS NULL;
```

Comment: after running all answers, I picked this answers as the correct answer due to its superiority in process time

Comment: @gordon - why do you think so? The OP stated this answer runs faster, and clearly both shouls return the same data.

Answer (score 1):

using `not exists()` to `count()` rows where `G` does not exist in `B` or `C`:

```
select count(*)
from A
where not exists (select 1 from B where A.G = B.G)
   or not exists (select 1 from C where A.G = C.G)
```

If you want to `count()` rows where `G` does not exist in both `B` and `C`, change `or` to `and` in the above code.

rextester example demo: http://rextester.com/MSVVN6153

Comment: as long as G cannot be represented more than once in table a there would not be a need for distinct can simply do a count but I also prefer exists for this type of query

Comment: @Matt Yes, if `G` is unique then `distinct` will incur unnecessary overhead and would should be removed.

Comment: Just to clarify, G is a unique in A, but nay repeat in B or C

Comment: @Meysa Thank you for the clarification, I updated my answer to remove the `distinct`.

Comment: 1. I want the query to show the number of people that are not in B, and not in C. So, I changed OR to AND;

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you want:

```
select count(*)
from a
where not exists (select 1 from b where a.g = b.g) and
      not exists (select 1 from c where a.g = c.g);
```

You specify:  "in A . . . that are not in either of B or C ".  This suggests that `G` doesn't exist in `B` *and* doesn't exist in `C`.  Hence the `and` rather than `or` (as in your version of the query).

I also removed the `count(distinct)`.  Instinct suggests that `a.g` is unique.  If not, then `count(distinct a.g)` is correct..

Answer (score 0):

And one last option using set operators you should learn. I'll leave counting out just to demonstrate the correctness:

```
set nocount on;
declare @a table (id smallint not null); 
declare @b table (id smallint not null, xx smallint not null); 
declare @c table (id smallint not null, yy smallint not null); 

insert @a(id) values (1), (2), (3), (4);
insert @b(id, xx) values (1,0), (1,1), (3, 0); 
insert @c(id, yy) values (1,9), (2, 1), (2,2), (5,1); -- notice the value 5 does not exist in @a

select id from @a except 
select id from @b except 
select id from @c
;
```

Comment: unfortunately I didn't get on how I can use this approach